# Reading a .json file, and getting an error

Tags: javascript, html, json, markers

I am trying to read a simple json datafile. But I keep getting the **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined"** error. I am unsure as to why. I have tried numerous attempts to change the structure of the json file but to no avail. Any assistance would be welcomed.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    var dataCoal = data.coal[i];

    // Creating a random position
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataCoal.lat,dataCoal.lon);


    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined


    // Creating a marker. Note that we don't add it to the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng
    });

    // Adding the marker to the markers array
    markers.push(marker);

  }
```

This is one entry in the JSON file

```
var data = { "coal": [{"NAME":"Haju Coal","Metals":"Coal","Lat":-0.11667,"Lon":114.85,"Accuracy":"approximate","DevStage":"Preproduction","ActStatus":"Temporarily On Hold","Company":"BHP Billiton Group","InSitu":700,"Metals_ft_style":0,"Accuracy_ft_style":0,"DevStage_ft_style":0,"ActStatus_ft_style":0}]}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you have a constant upper bound in your loop? What happens if you console.log(data.coal[0]) ? is Lat a property?

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < data.coal.length; i++) {` should fix it. Your current test of `i < 1000` goes past the end of the array to an undefined element, and an undefined element can't have properties. (Note also that that isn't JSON, your "JSON file" example is JavaScript code that creates a (nested) object via object- and array-literal syntax. JSON is a _string_ representation.)

Comment: Thanks guys. The actual JSON file has more than one entry. 1000 is a just a random I chose. I will change it to see if helps. This seemed to fix the error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should have something to signify an end to your loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
```

Other than that the only thing you have an error with is `lat` and `lon` being lowercased

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataCoal.Lat,dataCoal.Lon);
```

Should do the trick

So it should look like

```
var data = { "coal": [{"NAME":"Haju Coal","Metals":"Coal","Lat":-0.11667,"Lon":114.85,"Accuracy":"approximate","DevStage":"Preproduction","ActStatus":"Temporarily On Hold","Company":"BHP Billiton Group","InSitu":700,"Metals_ft_style":0,"Accuracy_ft_style":0,"DevStage_ft_style":0,"ActStatus_ft_style":0}]}
for (var i = 0; data.length < 1000; i++) {
    var dataCoal = data.coal[i];

    // Creating a random position
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(dataCoal.Lat, dataCoal.Lon);

    //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined


    // Creating a marker. Note that we don't add it to the map
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng
    });

    // Adding the marker to the markers array
    markers.push(marker);

}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

I think  the best way is to iterate over the data.coal like a foreach in PHP:

```
var coal;
for (var index in data.coal) {

  if (data.coal.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
    coal = data.coal[index];

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(coal.Lat, coal.Lon);

    // ...

  }
}
```